# List Most Recent File per Sub-Folder

Tags: bash, scripting, grep, ls

I have a File structure of :

```
FOLDER/SUB_FOLDER/Text_File
```

I have over 1k+ `FOLDER` and each `FOLDER` has at least 2 different `SUB_FOLDER` with each `SUB_FOLDER` their own `Text_File`.

I'm trying to challenge myself to generate a list of the most **recent** `Text_File` per `FOLDER/` (as a root)

```
My Pseudo code is (as well as commands I know right now): 
List all FOLDERS
 - **ls -t [EACH_FOLDER] | head -n1 **
    **ls -t EACH_FOLDER/SUB_FOLDER/**
      **ls Text_File**
```

Output should be:

```
/FOLDER/SUB_FOLDER/Text_File
```

...

all files.

My Goal is : I need to grep through each LATEST Text_File from each root `FOLDER` to parse information out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `gnu` you could try:

```
find "$(pwd)" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -printf "d%h\0%T@ %p\0" | awk -v RS="\0" '
  /^d/ {directoryname=substr($0,2)}
  /^[0-9]/ && (!lmtimes[directoryname] || lmtimes[directoryname] < $1) {
    lmtimes[directoryname]=$1;
    lmtimedns[directoryname]=substr($0,index($0," ")+1);
  }
  END {for (directoryname in lmtimedns) print lmtimedns[directoryname]}
  '
```

This version has been tested against weird names which contain special chars: `\n` `"` etc.

`$(pwd)` execute `pwd` command which prints the absolute pathname of the current directory.

`find $(pwd)` search the current directory, the full directory pathnames will be printed

The filter `-mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d` is selecting only directories at the second level where `FOLDER` in current directory are at level 1 and their `SUB_FOLDER` at level 2.

`-printf "d%h\0%T@ %p\0"` prints for each `SUBFOLDER` found, this information below:

`d` `FOLDER` `\0` `last modif time in second since EPOCH` `[space]` `SUBFOLDER` `\0` etc.

The `\0` cannot be part of a name so this is the perfect delimiter.

`awk -v RS="\0"` is considering `\0` as a Record Separator.

`/^d/ {directoryname=substr($0,2)}`: this `regex` is true when a record starts with `d`; `directoryname` variable is updated with the `FOLDER` name which is made of all chars right after the `d` char, by construction, thanks to `printf`.

`/^[0-9]/` : this `regex`is true when a record starts with a digit. By construction, thanks to `printf`, the first field (`$1`: e.g. all chars up to ̀`[space]` char) of the current record contains the last modified time.

`&& (!lmtimes[directoryname] || lmtimes[directoryname] < $1)`: **lmtimes** is an associative array (a Map of [key,value] pairs). It is used to store the newest last modification time of the current `SUBFOLDER` for the current `FOLDER` (`directoryname`). The expression is `true` if there is not yet a last modified time stored for `directoryname` or if the already stored last modified time is older than the one from the current `SUBFOLDER`.

When the later expression is true, both the last modified time and the name of `FOLDER` are stored using the `directoryname` key into **lmtimes** and **lmtimedns**, respectively.

`END {for (...`: When all records had been parsed, each `SUBFOLDER` name with newest last modified time are printed.

### ----

For history the command to list the filenames with most recent modification time for each directory:

```
 find "$(pwd)" -depth -type f -printf "d%h\0%T@ %p\0" | awk -v RS="\0" '
  /^d/ {
    directoryname=substr($0,2);
  }
  /^[0-9]/ {
    if (!lmtimes[directoryname] || lmtimes[directoryname] < $1) {
      lmtimes[directoryname]=$1;
      lmtimefns[directoryname]=substr($0,index($0," ")+1);
    }
  }
  END {
    for (directoryname in lmtimefns) {
      print lmtimefns[directoryname];
    }
  }'
```

Comment: Thank you Jay. I think there has to be two functions or iterations for this to work. The output here provided the Text_Files for every sub folder... My modification time should be based on folder modification does not need to go down to the FOLDER/SUB_FOLDER/**TEXTFILE.

Comment: @Bain This new version is listings for each `FOLDER` the `SUB_FOLDER` which has the most recent last modification time.

Comment: Thanks @Jay Jargot, this seemed to have worked correctly. NICE JOB! I wish I could get this good at bash scripts.

Comment: @Bain great! The answer has been updated with an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Array of root folders
folders=("a" "b")

# Search all specified root folders
for f in ${folders[@]}; do
    # Descend hierarchy and retrieve modification date of each file with "stat"
    find $f -type f -exec stat -f "%m,%N" {} ';' | \
        # sort by date, most recent first
        sort -gr | \
        # extract first (most recent) file
        head -1 | \
        # return file name only
        cut -d, -f2
done
```